# Grails search from one to many is not working

Tags: grails

Here are my domain class,

```
class Company {
    String name
    static hasMany = [groups:CompanyGroup]
}

class CompanyGroup{
    String name
    static belongsTo = [company:Company]
}
```

I receive params that contain name of CompanyGroup and I want to get the result of company that have the CompanyGroup found.

I did like this,

```
def groupList = account.companies.groups.flatten()
def groupResult = groupList.findAll{
    it.name ==~  /(?i).*${params.keyword}.*/ 
}
```

I got the Companygroups that have name from params.key from above code. So I want to render company list that have these group like this,

```
def com = Company.withCriteria{
  eq("groups", groupList)
}
render [companies : com]
```

It doesn't work!

Comment: I couldn't able to get ur problem correctly, but it is giving me an idea,.. you have search for some called `inList`

Comment: isn't it `inList` and not `eq`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def com = Company.withCriteria{
  inList("groups", groupList)
}
```